# Entity Framework: Can I make two separate queries in one request?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to make two queries to different tables in one request?

For example, if I have this DBContext:

```
public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
public DbSet<Farmer> Farmers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Llama> Llamas { get; set; }
```

And these classes:

```
public class Farm
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Farmer> Farmers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Farmer> Llamas { get; set; }
}

public class Farmer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid FarmID { get; set; }

    public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
}

public class Llama
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid FarmID { get; set; }

    public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be possible to make these two queries in one query?

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetInhabitants(Guid farmID)
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();

    IEnumerable<Farmer> farmers = db.Farmers.Where(x => x.FarmID == farmID);
    IEnumerable<Llama> llamas = db.Llamas.Where(x => x.FarmID == farmID);

    return [this would be easier if I could make one query]
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, would it return?  A FarmerLlama class?

Comment: ManBearLlama? object? Some sort of dataset with both farmers and llamas? Or are you essentially saying this isn't possible?

Comment: I think you should applied `MVVM` in your case. Create a `ViewModel` which hold properties of both `Farmer` and `Llama` class which you want to display in your view

Comment: The problem is not in what the function should return, that would be a trivial problem to solve either way. This is a question about the capabilities of EF, apologies if this example didn't represent that very well.

Comment: Basically, you can make as many database query as you want on one request call. But keep in mind that this will affect performance and maybe lead to request time out if your queries running for too long

Comment: Since Farm has navigational properties, would not getting a farm with farmid give  access to both farmers and llamas ?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana I appreciate that but this was a question about executing two queries in one request rather than the specific, and as stated above, flawed example I provided. Apologies for any confusion!

Answer (score -1):

Given your particular setup, I believe you could do

```
return db.Farmers.Where(x => x.FarmID == farmID)
       .Union(db.Llama.Where(x => x.FarmID == farmID));
```

(Note: I'm writing this off the top of my head, so the syntax might be a bit off).

Edited to add:
You might want to look up deferred execution.  If you are using an IQueryable object, you can make as many Entity Framework requests as you'd like in the code, but it won't actually execute them until you trigger the execution (typically by calling .ToList()).

Comment: Farmers and Llamas don't share a common base class. You can't union them like this unless you project them both to an anonymous object of the same properties.

Comment: The spirit of the answer is correct, even if the syntax isn't quite right (which I plainly said).  The OP was asking if it was possible to combine 2 LINQ queries into a single query.  Union is one approach to do this.